# how to parse nested json using javascripts

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code for snow rest outbound  call and this is working as expected., but in the second rest call i am trying to parse the json body but i am unable to retrieve the values. here by iam attaching the sample copy of expected output

```
 try { 
 var r = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2('test', 'post');

 var response = r.execute();
 var responseBody = response.getBody();
 var httpStatus = response.getStatusCode();
 gs.print(response.getBody());
 gs.print(response.getStatusCode());
 var JsonObject = JSON.parse(responseBody);
 var sid = JsonObject.sid; 
 gs.print(sid);

 var r1 = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2('gateways', 'POST' );
 r1.setRequestHeader("X-chkp-sid",sid );
 var response1 = r1.execute();
 var responseBody1 = response1.getBody();
 var httpStatus = response1.getStatusCode()
 gs.print(response1.getBody());
 var JsonObject1 = JSON.parse(responseBody1);
 var objects = JsonObject1.objects;

 var database = new GlideRecord('u_test');
 database.initialize();
 database.query();
 database.deleteMultiple();

for (var key in objects) { // Loop through all the elements in the objects array

    var array_element=objects[key];

    for (var innerKey in array_element)//For each element, see if it contains key named cluster-member-names
        {
        if(innerKey == "cluster-member-names"){
            var cluster_array = array_element[innerKey];

            for (var clusterKey in cluster_array)// Print each element in the Cluster array 
                {
                gs.print(cluster_array[clusterKey]);
                                test = cluster_array[clusterKey];
                                gs.print(test);
                                var database = new GlideRecord('u_test');
                                database.initialize();
                                database.u_device = test;
                                database.insert();

            }
        }
    }
}
}
catch(ex) {
 var message = ex.message;
}
```

sample json

```
{
  "objects" : [ {
    "uid" : "16b96771-d13a-4c11-b457-9c0861aaf3c8",
    "name" : "clus-cn-1",
    "type" : "CpmiGatewayCluster",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6",
      "name" : "dom-cn-1",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : {
      "access-policy-installed" : true,
      "access-policy-name" : "Standard",
      "access-policy-installation-date" : {
        "posix" : 1533629226178,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:07+0800"
      },
      "threat-policy-installed" : false
    },
    "operating-system" : "Gaia",
    "hardware" : "Open server",
    "version" : "R80",
    "ipv4-address" : "10.126.102.12",
    "network-security-blades" : {
      "firewall" : true,
      "site-to-site-vpn" : true
    },
    "management-blades" : { },
    "cluster-member-names" : [ "dev-cn-c1", "dev-cn-c2" ],
    "vpn-encryption-domain" : "addresses_behind_gw",
    "sic-status" : "uninitialized",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/cluster",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533629193330,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:06+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533629186803,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:06+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "385c0a22-275c-4a70-9489-2b6ccd191eb8",
    "name" : "clus-cn-2",
    "type" : "CpmiGatewayCluster",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "6c2f639f-db32-4255-88ef-fb9b0e820051",
      "name" : "dom-cn-2",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : {
      "access-policy-installed" : true,
      "access-policy-name" : "Standard",
      "access-policy-installation-date" : {
        "posix" : 1533631724838,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:48+0800"
      },
      "threat-policy-installed" : false
    },
    "operating-system" : "Gaia",
    "hardware" : "Open server",
    "version" : "R80",
    "ipv4-address" : "10.126.102.16",
    "network-security-blades" : {
      "firewall" : true
    },
    "management-blades" : { },
    "cluster-member-names" : [ "dev-cn-c3", "dev-cn-c4" ],
    "vpn-encryption-domain" : "addresses_behind_gw",
    "sic-status" : "uninitialized",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/cluster",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533631690759,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:48+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533630083711,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:21+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "4652da03-0e2f-4a0a-880c-338396be0818",
    "name" : "dev-cn-c1",
    "type" : "CpmiClusterMember",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6",
      "name" : "dom-cn-1",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : { },
    "ipv4-address" : "10.126.102.9",
    "interfaces" : [ {
      "interface-name" : "eth1",
      "ipv4-address" : "10.10.10.1",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.240",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 28,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : false,
        "ip-address-behind-this-interface" : "network defined by the interface ip and net mask",
        "leads-to-dmz" : false
      }
    }, {
      "interface-name" : "eth0",
      "ipv4-address" : "10.126.102.9",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.192",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 26,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : true
      }
    } ],
    "sic-status" : "communicating",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/Cluster_member",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533629193630,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:06+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533629187252,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:06+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "2dbbbfd4-80ac-4fd9-b792-0a5b468c6409",
    "name" : "dev-cn-c2",
    "type" : "CpmiClusterMember",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6",
      "name" : "dom-cn-1",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : { },
    "ipv4-address" : "10.126.102.10",
    "interfaces" : [ {
      "interface-name" : "eth1",
      "ipv4-address" : "10.10.10.2",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.240",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 28,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : false,
        "ip-address-behind-this-interface" : "network defined by the interface ip and net mask",
        "leads-to-dmz" : false
      }
    }, {
      "interface-name" : "eth0",
      "ipv4-address" : "10.126.102.10",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.192",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 26,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : true
      }
    } ],
    "sic-status" : "communicating",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/Cluster_member",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533629193427,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:06+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533629188258,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:06+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "6037e235-f19a-49ac-a39c-4889d979acbe",
    "name" : "dev-cn-c3",
    "type" : "CpmiClusterMember",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "6c2f639f-db32-4255-88ef-fb9b0e820051",
      "name" : "dom-cn-2",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : { },
    "ipv4-address" : "10.126.102.13",
    "interfaces" : [ {
      "interface-name" : "eth0",
      "ipv4-address" : "10.126.102.13",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.192",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 26,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : true
      }
    }, {
      "interface-name" : "eth1",
      "ipv4-address" : "10.10.20.1",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.240",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 28,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : false,
        "ip-address-behind-this-interface" : "network defined by the interface ip and net mask",
        "leads-to-dmz" : false
      }
    } ],
    "sic-status" : "communicating",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/Cluster_member",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533631689704,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:48+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533630084104,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:21+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "022c44df-9271-46db-b782-da084c476dd2",
    "name" : "dev-cn-c4",
    "type" : "CpmiClusterMember",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "6c2f639f-db32-4255-88ef-fb9b0e820051",
      "name" : "dom-cn-2",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : { },
    "ipv4-address" : "10.126.102.14",
    "interfaces" : [ {
      "interface-name" : "eth0",
      "ipv4-address" : "10.126.102.14",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.192",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 26,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : true
      }
    }, {
      "interface-name" : "eth1",
      "ipv4-address" : "10.10.20.2",
      "ipv4-network-mask" : "255.255.255.240",
      "ipv4-mask-length" : 28,
      "dynamic-ip" : false,
      "topology" : {
        "leads-to-internet" : false,
        "ip-address-behind-this-interface" : "network defined by the interface ip and net mask",
        "leads-to-dmz" : false
      }
    } ],
    "sic-status" : "communicating",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/Cluster_member",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533631690171,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:48+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533630085006,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T16:21+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "4f417c60-3541-4c0f-a542-9a100d857077",
    "name" : "dom_cn_1_Server",
    "type" : "CpmiHostCkp",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6",
      "name" : "dom-cn-1",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : { },
    "operating-system" : "Unknown OS",
    "hardware" : "Open server",
    "version" : "R80.10",
    "ipv4-address" : "10.126.102.11",
    "network-security-blades" : { },
    "management-blades" : {
      "network-policy-management" : true,
      "logging-and-status" : true
    },
    "sic-status" : "uninitialized",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/CheckPoint/Hosts/xHost_CP",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "Domain Management Server",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533621654552,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T14:00+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533621625970,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T14:00+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  }, {
    "uid" : "cebecd33-1efb-4530-9de9-7c666e588ee7",
    "name" : "dom_cn_2_Server",
    "type" : "CpmiHostCkp",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "6c2f639f-db32-4255-88ef-fb9b0e820051",
      "name" : "dom-cn-2",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "policy" : { },
    "operating-system" : "Unknown OS",
    "hardware" : "Open server",
    "version" : "R80.10",
    "ipv4-address" : "10.126.102.15",
    "network-security-blades" : { },
    "management-blades" : {
      "network-policy-management" : true,
      "logging-and-status" : true
    },
    "sic-status" : "uninitialized",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "icon" : "NetworkObjects/CheckPoint/Hosts/xHost_CP",
    "groups" : [ ],
    "comments" : "Domain Management Server",
    "color" : "black",
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533627992781,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T15:46+0800"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "System",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1533627964438,
        "iso-8601" : "2018-08-07T15:46+0800"
      },
      "creator" : "System"
    },
    "read-only" : true
  } ],
  "from" : 1,
  "to" : 8,
  "total" : 8
}
```

expected output .

[image: image description]

Answer (score 0):

Use a for-loop to iterate through JsonObject1.objects, like so:

`for(var i = 0; i < JsonObject1.objects.length; i++)`

Then access the elements like so:

`JsonObject1.objects[i].name` or `JsonObject1.objects[i]['operating-system']`

Comment: problem with this approach , i am getting only one value for specific key

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```js
var data = {"objects":[{"uid":"16b96771-d13a-4c11-b457-9c0861aaf3c8","name":"clus-cn-1","type":"CpmiGatewayCluster","domain":{"uid":"16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6","name":"dom-cn-1","domain-type":"domain"},"policy":{"access-policy-installed":true,"access-policy-name":"Standard","access-policy-installation-date":{"posix":1533629226178,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:07+0800"},"threat-policy-installed":false},"operating-system":"Gaia","hardware":"Open server","version":"R80","ipv4-address":"10.126.102.12","network-security-blades":{"firewall":true,"site-to-site-vpn":true},"management-blades":{},"cluster-member-names":["dev-cn-c1","dev-cn-c2"],"vpn-encryption-domain":"addresses_behind_gw","sic-status":"uninitialized","tags":[],"icon":"NetworkObjects/cluster","groups":[],"comments":"","color":"black","meta-info":{"lock":"unlocked","validation-state":"ok","last-modify-time":{"posix":1533629193330,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:06+0800"},"last-modifier":"System","creation-time":{"posix":1533629186803,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:06+0800"},"creator":"System"},"read-only":true},{"uid":"385c0a22-275c-4a70-9489-2b6ccd191eb8","name":"clus-cn-2","type":"CpmiGatewayCluster","domain":{"uid":"6c2f639f-db32-4255-88ef-fb9b0e820051","name":"dom-cn-2","domain-type":"domain"},"policy":{"access-policy-installed":true,"access-policy-name":"Standard","access-policy-installation-date":{"posix":1533631724838,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:48+0800"},"threat-policy-installed":false},"operating-system":"Gaia","hardware":"Open server","version":"R80","ipv4-address":"10.126.102.16","network-security-blades":{"firewall":true},"management-blades":{},"cluster-member-names":["dev-cn-c3","dev-cn-c4"],"vpn-encryption-domain":"addresses_behind_gw","sic-status":"uninitialized","tags":[],"icon":"NetworkObjects/cluster","groups":[],"comments":"","color":"black","meta-info":{"lock":"unlocked","validation-state":"ok","last-modify-time":{"posix":1533631690759,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:48+0800"},"last-modifier":"System","creation-time":{"posix":1533630083711,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:21+0800"},"creator":"System"},"read-only":true},{"uid":"4652da03-0e2f-4a0a-880c-338396be0818","name":"dev-cn-c1","type":"CpmiClusterMember","domain":{"uid":"16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6","name":"dom-cn-1","domain-type":"domain"},"policy":{},"ipv4-address":"10.126.102.9","interfaces":[{"interface-name":"eth1","ipv4-address":"10.10.10.1","ipv4-network-mask":"255.255.255.240","ipv4-mask-length":28,"dynamic-ip":false,"topology":{"leads-to-internet":false,"ip-address-behind-this-interface":"network defined by the interface ip and net mask","leads-to-dmz":false}},{"interface-name":"eth0","ipv4-address":"10.126.102.9","ipv4-network-mask":"255.255.255.192","ipv4-mask-length":26,"dynamic-ip":false,"topology":{"leads-to-internet":true}}],"sic-status":"communicating","tags":[],"icon":"NetworkObjects/Cluster_member","groups":[],"comments":"","color":"black","meta-info":{"lock":"unlocked","validation-state":"ok","last-modify-time":{"posix":1533629193630,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:06+0800"},"last-modifier":"System","creation-time":{"posix":1533629187252,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:06+0800"},"creator":"System"},"read-only":true},{"uid":"2dbbbfd4-80ac-4fd9-b792-0a5b468c6409","name":"dev-cn-c2","type":"CpmiClusterMember","domain":{"uid":"16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6","name":"dom-cn-1","domain-type":"domain"},"policy":{},"ipv4-address":"10.126.102.10","interfaces":[{"interface-name":"eth1","ipv4-address":"10.10.10.2","ipv4-network-mask":"255.255.255.240","ipv4-mask-length":28,"dynamic-ip":false,"topology":{"leads-to-internet":false,"ip-address-behind-this-interface":"network defined by the interface ip and net mask","leads-to-dmz":false}},{"interface-name":"eth0","ipv4-address":"10.126.102.10","ipv4-network-mask":"255.255.255.192","ipv4-mask-length":26,"dynamic-ip":false,"topology":{"leads-to-internet":true}}],"sic-status":"communicating","tags":[],"icon":"NetworkObjects/Cluster_member","groups":[],"comments":"","color":"black","meta-info":{"lock":"unlocked","validation-state":"ok","last-modify-time":{"posix":1533629193427,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:06+0800"},"last-modifier":"System","creation-time":{"posix":1533629188258,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:06+0800"},"creator":"System"},"read-only":true},{"uid":"6037e235-f19a-49ac-a39c-4889d979acbe","name":"dev-cn-c3","type":"CpmiClusterMember","domain":{"uid":"6c2f639f-db32-4255-88ef-fb9b0e820051","name":"dom-cn-2","domain-type":"domain"},"policy":{},"ipv4-address":"10.126.102.13","interfaces":[{"interface-name":"eth0","ipv4-address":"10.126.102.13","ipv4-network-mask":"255.255.255.192","ipv4-mask-length":26,"dynamic-ip":false,"topology":{"leads-to-internet":true}},{"interface-name":"eth1","ipv4-address":"10.10.20.1","ipv4-network-mask":"255.255.255.240","ipv4-mask-length":28,"dynamic-ip":false,"topology":{"leads-to-internet":false,"ip-address-behind-this-interface":"network defined by the interface ip and net mask","leads-to-dmz":false}}],"sic-status":"communicating","tags":[],"icon":"NetworkObjects/Cluster_member","groups":[],"comments":"","color":"black","meta-info":{"lock":"unlocked","validation-state":"ok","last-modify-time":{"posix":1533631689704,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:48+0800"},"last-modifier":"System","creation-time":{"posix":1533630084104,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:21+0800"},"creator":"System"},"read-only":true},{"uid":"022c44df-9271-46db-b782-da084c476dd2","name":"dev-cn-c4","type":"CpmiClusterMember","domain":{"uid":"6c2f639f-db32-4255-88ef-fb9b0e820051","name":"dom-cn-2","domain-type":"domain"},"policy":{},"ipv4-address":"10.126.102.14","interfaces":[{"interface-name":"eth0","ipv4-address":"10.126.102.14","ipv4-network-mask":"255.255.255.192","ipv4-mask-length":26,"dynamic-ip":false,"topology":{"leads-to-internet":true}},{"interface-name":"eth1","ipv4-address":"10.10.20.2","ipv4-network-mask":"255.255.255.240","ipv4-mask-length":28,"dynamic-ip":false,"topology":{"leads-to-internet":false,"ip-address-behind-this-interface":"network defined by the interface ip and net mask","leads-to-dmz":false}}],"sic-status":"communicating","tags":[],"icon":"NetworkObjects/Cluster_member","groups":[],"comments":"","color":"black","meta-info":{"lock":"unlocked","validation-state":"ok","last-modify-time":{"posix":1533631690171,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:48+0800"},"last-modifier":"System","creation-time":{"posix":1533630085006,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T16:21+0800"},"creator":"System"},"read-only":true},{"uid":"4f417c60-3541-4c0f-a542-9a100d857077","name":"dom_cn_1_Server","type":"CpmiHostCkp","domain":{"uid":"16280a32-183a-4050-b698-f59dbe488da6","name":"dom-cn-1","domain-type":"domain"},"policy":{},"operating-system":"Unknown OS","hardware":"Open server","version":"R80.10","ipv4-address":"10.126.102.11","network-security-blades":{},"management-blades":{"network-policy-management":true,"logging-and-status":true},"sic-status":"uninitialized","tags":[],"icon":"NetworkObjects/CheckPoint/Hosts/xHost_CP","groups":[],"comments":"Domain Management Server","color":"black","meta-info":{"lock":"unlocked","validation-state":"ok","last-modify-time":{"posix":1533621654552,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T14:00+0800"},"last-modifier":"System","creation-time":{"posix":1533621625970,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T14:00+0800"},"creator":"System"},"read-only":true},{"uid":"cebecd33-1efb-4530-9de9-7c666e588ee7","name":"dom_cn_2_Server","type":"CpmiHostCkp","domain":{"uid":"6c2f639f-db32-4255-88ef-fb9b0e820051","name":"dom-cn-2","domain-type":"domain"},"policy":{},"operating-system":"Unknown OS","hardware":"Open server","version":"R80.10","ipv4-address":"10.126.102.15","network-security-blades":{},"management-blades":{"network-policy-management":true,"logging-and-status":true},"sic-status":"uninitialized","tags":[],"icon":"NetworkObjects/CheckPoint/Hosts/xHost_CP","groups":[],"comments":"Domain Management Server","color":"black","meta-info":{"lock":"unlocked","validation-state":"ok","last-modify-time":{"posix":1533627992781,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T15:46+0800"},"last-modifier":"System","creation-time":{"posix":1533627964438,"iso-8601":"2018-08-07T15:46+0800"},"creator":"System"},"read-only":true}],"from":1,"to":8,"total":8};

  for(obj of data.objects){
    console.log("NAME:", obj.domain.name);
    console.log("DOMAIN NAME: ", obj.name);
    console.log("OS: ", obj["operating-system"]);
    var members = obj["cluster-member-names"];
    if(members){
        console.log("CLUSTER MEMBERS: ", members[0] + "," + members[1]);
    }
    console.log("UID: ", obj.domain.uid);
    console.log("--------------------------------");
  }
```